# user first_name last_name fields to create a full_name field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, migration

I have  `first_name` and `last_name` fields currently represented in my model in rails. I'd like to add another field to my database called `full_name` and was wondering what the best way to do this seamlessly would be. Mind you I also have a production server going and would like to make it so that I not only add a column in my migration, but also can populate the new field with the existing data.

EDIT:

Here's my controller

```
def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @followers = @user.followers.find(:all, :select => 'users.id, users.first_name, users.last_name', :conditions => ["users.first_name like ?","%" + params[:q] + "%"])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {render 'show_follow'}
      format.json {render :json => @followers}
    end
end
```

I want to be able to 1. `select: 'users.id, users.full_name` and 2. `:condition =>["users.full_name like ?", ...]` and the only way I can think to do this is to modify the model. I also only want to return the properties `id` and `full_name` in the json object.

Comment: Is it compulsory to have full_name in database if you create helper method with the join of fist_name and last_name?

Comment: thing is i want to be able to send a json object from the controller with the `full_name` and `id`. Right now my controller looks like the above and I can't figure out how to use the helper method...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will probably be better off just defining a full_name method in your model:

```
def full_name                                                                                                                                                                                     
  ([first_name, last_name] - ['']).compact.join(' ')                         
end
```

You can search by full name with something like:

```
def self.find_all_by_name_containing(text)
  self.where("LOWER(first_name || ' ' || last_name) LIKE ?", "%#{text.downcase}%")
end
```

Then define your own #to_json

Comment: so how would i implement that in my controller so that json only returns `id` and `full_name`?

Comment: You can use like render :json => @followers.to_json( :only => [:id], :methods => [:full_name])

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to go ahead with adding a `full_name` field to your `User` model, then I suggest the following steps.

1.Generate a rails migration adding the field `full_name` to `users` table.

```
rails g migration add_full_name_to_users full_name:string
```

2.Add the following `before_save` callback to your `User` model.

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  before_save :set_full_name

  private
  def set_full_name
    self.full_name = "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}".strip
  end
end
```

3.Commit, push code to production, run migration on production.

4.Run a `save` or `save!` method on all your users in rails console.

```
$> User.find_each(:batch_size => 1000){ |user| user.save }
```

I guess, that should take care of updating your existing users, plus the `before_save` call will take care of future additions/updates.

Comment: Works great thanks!  Anyone running though be warned: this will run all actions set as `before_save` - i.e. Devise confirmation emails will be sent out

Answer (score 0):

Generate migration

```
rails g migration add_full_name_to_users
```

Inside migration:

```
def up
  add_column :users, :full_name, :string
  execute <<-SQL
    UPDATE users SET full_name = first_name||' '||last_name WHERE full_name IS NULL;
  SQL
end
```

It will create full_name column and populate it with default data. You can also do something like this in ruby but it will be much faster in SQL.